# How can I distribute a pool to a given number of items within a given range

Tags: java, algorithm

So I have a number of bottles, for example 1000, and a given number of boxes, for example 10. I need to store the bottles in the boxes but randomly and within a range. So what does it mean? For example If I say that my range is 5% to 50% than  I need to take those 1000 boxes and distribute them to my 10 boxes starting at 50 per box and ending at 500 per box. Each one of those 10 boxes MUST get a number between 50 to 500, they must be bottles in them. Currently I am just dividing the whole thing equally as such:

```
private static int[] splitIntoChunks(int bottles,int boxes) {
    int[] arr = new int[bottles];
    int remain = boxes;
    int partsLeft = bottles;
    for (int i = 0; partsLeft > 0; i++) {
        int size = (remain + partsLeft - 1) / partsLeft;
        arr[i] = size;
        remain -= size;
        partsLeft--;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I am trying to find our the most elegant solution considering the fact that my range is also influenced by the number of bottles and boxes.

Comment: It's not quite clear what do you mean by "entities" and "items".

Comment: Thanks, I tried to clarify it with an example that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it the following way. First fill up all boxes with the minimal value of bottles. Then pick randomly a box and add a bottle if not the maximum is exceeded. This is not the fastest solution, but I think it's an easy and robust solution.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyClass {
    
    private static final Random random = new Random(123);
    
    private static int[] splitIntoChunks(int bottles,int boxes, double lower, double upper) {
        int[] arr = new int[boxes];
        int remain = bottles;
        int minBottles = (int) Math.round(bottles * lower);
        int maxBottles = (int) Math.round(bottles * upper);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = minBottles;
            remain -= minBottles;
        }
        
        while(remain > 0) {
            int i = random.nextInt(arr.length);
            if( arr[i] >= maxBottles ) {
                continue;
            }
            arr[i] += 1;
            remain -= 1;
        }
        
        return arr;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitIntoChunks(1000,10, 5.0/100.5, 50.0/100.0)));
    }
}
```

Output

```
[98, 112, 106, 91, 94, 96, 101, 116, 86, 100]
```

Notice: There is no check if there is no such a solution with lower and upper bounds. But this is easy to implement.

Comment: Super creative idea! thank you very much!